# Extract text between brackets in character column (create new column) of R dataframe

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Apologies if the title is a bit wordy, hopefully this example will be helpful. I have the following dataset:

```
my_df
                                     Description thisYVal thisPts
1                     (12:00)   Start Period        0       0
2        (12:00)   Jump Ball Thomas vs Grant        0       0
3      (11:48) [MIA 3-] Wade Layup Shot: Missed     0       2
4  (11:46) [PHL] Thomas Rebound (Off: Def:1)        0       0
6     (11:02) [MIA] Haslem Jump Shot: Missed      -19       2
7  (11:00) [MIA] Haslem Rebound (Off:1 Def:)        0       0
8    (10:57) [MIA] Haslem Layup Shot: Missed        0       2
9 (10:56) [PHL] Coleman Rebound (Off: Def:1)        0       0

dput(my_df)
structure(list(Description = c("(12:00)   Start Period", "(12:00)   Jump Ball Thomas vs Grant", 
"(11:48) [MIA 3-] Wade Layup Shot: Missed", "(11:46) [PHL] Thomas Rebound (Off: Def:1)", 
"(11:02) [MIA] Haslem Jump Shot: Missed", "(11:00) [MIA] Haslem Rebound (Off:1 Def:)", 
"(10:57) [MIA] Haslem Layup Shot: Missed", "(10:56) [PHL] Coleman Rebound (Off: Def:1)"
), thisYVal = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, -19L, 0L, 0L, 0L), thisPts = c(0L, 
0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 0L)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

... and I would like to extract the 3-letter team abbreviation that appears in the `Description` column of the dataframe.

The 3-letter description **always** follows the first opening-square-bracket **[**, although it is not always followed by the closing bracket **]** (as you can see in row 3 of the dataframe).

I have been trying to do this using the substr() function but have had no luck so far. Any help is appreciated !

EDIT: some additional context - some rows (1 and 2, in this case) do not have a [] or a team-abbreviation. In these instances, the dataframe could return a blank string, an NA, or something else.

EDIT-2: just incase since it wasnt explicitly mentioned - a 4th column with `c("", "", "MIA", "PHL", "MIA", "MIA", "MIA", "PHL")` is what I am trying to get

Edit-3: The following gets me close, but not quite there

```
my_df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(teamAbb = unlist(stringr::str_extract(Description, "\\[(.*)\\]")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_match` from the [`stringr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html) package. Specifically, you will want to look for three capitalized letters (assuming *all* team abbreviations are three letters) after a left square bracket.

```
> str_match(df$Description, '\\[([A-Z]{3})')
     [,1]   [,2] 
[1,] NA     NA   
[2,] NA     NA   
[3,] "[MIA" "MIA"
[4,] "[PHL" "PHL"
[5,] "[MIA" "MIA"
[6,] "[MIA" "MIA"
[7,] "[MIA" "MIA"
[8,] "[PHL" "PHL"
```

You'll note that the team abbreviation pattern is actually in parenthesis; that's because it's a [subgroup](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) of the pattern that we want to extract. As such, `str_match` returns (1) the entire pattern, and (2) the subgroup(s) specified in parenthesis. Therefore, in this case, we want to take the second column, which contains matches from the *first* subgroup.

```
df$Team <- str_match(df$Description, '\\[([A-Z]{3})')[,2]
```

This gives us the desired result:

```
                                 Description Team
1                     (12:00)   Start Period <NA>
2        (12:00)   Jump Ball Thomas vs Grant <NA>
3  (11:48) [MIA 3-] Wade Layup Shot: Missed   MIA
4  (11:46) [PHL] Thomas Rebound (Off: Def:1)  PHL
5     (11:02) [MIA] Haslem Jump Shot: Missed  MIA
6  (11:00) [MIA] Haslem Rebound (Off:1 Def:)  MIA
7    (10:57) [MIA] Haslem Layup Shot: Missed  MIA
8 (10:56) [PHL] Coleman Rebound (Off: Def:1)  PHL
```

Answer (score 2):

R recently introduced `strcapture` to its standard `utils` package:

```
strcapture("(?<=\\[)(.{3})", dat$Description, proto=list(out=character()), perl=TRUE)
#   out
#1 <NA>
#2 <NA>
#3  MIA
#4  PHL
#5  MIA
#6  MIA
#7  MIA
#8  PHL
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option that looks for 3 non-digits after a bracket and places them in a new column called Team:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(Team = str_extract(Description, "(?<=\\[)\\D{3}"))
#>                                  Description thisYVal thisPts Team
#> 1                     (12:00)   Start Period        0       0 <NA>
#> 2        (12:00)   Jump Ball Thomas vs Grant        0       0 <NA>
#> 3   (11:48) [MIA 3-] Wade Layup Shot: Missed        0       2  MIA
#> 4  (11:46) [PHL] Thomas Rebound (Off: Def:1)        0       0  PHL
#> 5     (11:02) [MIA] Haslem Jump Shot: Missed      -19       2  MIA
#> 6  (11:00) [MIA] Haslem Rebound (Off:1 Def:)        0       0  MIA
#> 7    (10:57) [MIA] Haslem Layup Shot: Missed        0       2  MIA
#> 8 (10:56) [PHL] Coleman Rebound (Off: Def:1)        0       0  PHL
```

Created on 2018-09-09 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).